# Regex for custom verification of string

Tags: regex

I need to make a regex pattern to check if whole input string is made out of characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 without spaces in the middle. I tried using `^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9][ ]*$` to find but it doesn't work for some reason.

For example, `"   dnsjkfs32NJ"`  is a valid string but `"fds fsdfs"` is not.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Where are you using this regex? Perl? PHP? Ruby? grep? C#?

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*$
```

You're missing a `+` after your character class; without it, it's matching one and only one character.

Comment: `\s` is any whitespace: space, tab, etc.

Comment: personally, I'd use a trim function, instead of whitespace matching.  Personal preference, but I find I often need to trim the string anyway.